# Selecting ids with max ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get all the ids that has the maximum year and sem?

```
SELECT  m.ID,
    MAX(m.Year) as MaxYearLevel,
    m.Sem
    FROM
(SELECT t1.ID AS StudentID,
        t1.Year,
        t1.Sem
 FROM table1 t1) AS m
 GROUP BY m.ID;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `MAX()`? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: Share the query you've tried and the expected result set. It's difficult to construct a query for you based on theoretical requirements.

Comment: Yeah I have tried MAX() but it only gives the first row of every ID.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

just perform an order by

```
Select * from [Your table] order by year DESC, sem DESC
```

and specify how many row you want to take

ORACLE SQL:

```
Select * from [Your table] order by year DESC, sem DESC fetch first x rows only
```

SQL:

```
select Top(x) * from [Your table] order by year DESC, sem DESC
```